# Splitting string gives null result in java

Tags: java

i am trying very simple splitting. 
I dont know why it is not working.

```
String abc= "192.168.120.2";
String[] eachByteabc= abc.split(".");
```

When I debug it and see, I get the result that abc contains : 192.168.120.2.
But when I do split, it does not give me error but gives me null result.
I think, i have made some silly mistake. 
Can you tell me where I am wrong. What should I do.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: just tested it and your array splits properly.

Comment: The dot in regex speak means 'one character'.

Comment: Try using `abc.split("\\.");`

Comment: If you want to understand *why*, check out the Java API for string and then read the javadoc for Pattern (Google is your friend.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it =):

```
String[] eachByteabc= abc.split("\\.");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `.`, since it's a regex operator. Change it to:

```
String[] eachByteabc= abc.split("[.]");
```

Addition, thanks to ***@sparks***:

> While this will work, the [] characters in regex are used to annotate
>   a set, so if you are looking for where it might be in a limited series
>   of characters, you should use them.

In this case - use `\\.` to escape the `.` character.

Comment: while this will work, the `[]` characters in regex are used to annotate a set, so if you are looking for where it might be in a limited series of characters, you should use them. However, since they are only looking for a single specific character, its better practice to just use the specific character (in this case `"\\."`) both WILL work, just a best practice thing.

Comment: Thanks, can I add your note to the answer ?

Comment: feel free. Knowledge all around!

Answer (score 2):

`public String[] split(String regex)` takes a regular expression as an argument. You must escape the point, since it's a regex operator.

Comment: He gets a correct split, but the array is splitted to every character in the String.

Answer (score 1):

String[] eachByteabc = abc.split("."); is not eorr,but you can not to debug and Watch the values.use String[] eachByteabc = abc.split(".");you can Watch values in the debug.

Comment: last String[] eachByteabc = abc.split(".") is String[] eachByteabc = abc.split("\\.")

Answer (score 0):

String.split uses regex, so you need to use `abc.split("\\.");`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: That won't compile.  You need another '\' in the string.

Comment: \ is a special character itself, you need to escape it as well.

Comment: Bah, Gets me everytime. I'm used to regex not inside of Java. answer updated